# how to get async redux initialState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to get some of my initialState from server, before react-redux app mounted.

Right now I'm using this code:

```
//store.js (pseudocode)
const initialState = {
  userDate: {
    loggedIn:false,
    name: ""
  }
};

(async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("user/profile", { withCredentials: true });
  if (data.name) {
    initialState.userData = {
      ...initialState.userData,
      loggedIn: true,
      name: data.name
    };
  };

  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState
  );

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
})();
```

But I think it is not "redux-style", and also, I wanna manage my initalState in reducers, not in root file, something like this:

```
//userReduce.js (pseudocode)
const initialState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    name: ""
  };

const { data } = await axios.get("user/profile", { withCredentials: true });
if (data.name) {
  initialState = {
    loggedIn: true,
    name: data.name
  };
}

export default function userData(state = initialState, action) {
...
}
```

I know that I can make async actions to get data, but problem is while action dispatching, app already mounted, and redirect user as if he was not logged in.

Comment: Start with normal initialState, and in your App component fetch data (in componentDidMount life cycle hook) for the state you want to begin. then update your redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution n.1

The "redux way" would be to produce the full initial state on the server and serve it `JSON.stringify({})` in your HTML like `window.__REDUX_STATE__ = {...}`.

This way your React App could boot synchronously.

#### Solution n.2

If you really want it to be asynchronous and load the state from an API **after** the page loads, you could try to do something like:

1. fetch the full state (you also want to compose different sub-states... take a look at GraphQL!) and await the JSON response
2. boot your React App synchronously with the initial state

---

**NOTE:** I would go for n.1 as is the fastest when it comes to time to first meaningful frame. Instagram does it that way :-)